# Deploy webapp to azure password

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, credentials

I deployed my webapp to azure, choosing create new option
which created a new App Service and App Service plan.

My code is shared on dropbox. When I tried to build and deploy from
another laptop, it does not allow due to wrong credential.

The password was created automatically during my deployment from
the other laptop. Where should I check to get the credential password
so I can deploy from my second laptop?

Comment: try deploy using the publishing profile information (as told by Boland'answer) via Filezilla or similar FTP software. Especially if you are working from multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

The publish profile, containing the password, can be found this way:

Click the link in Azure portal -> Your Website -> Dashboard -> Quick glance -> Download the publish profile.

Download the file and your publishing password should be there in plain text in form userPWD="7vasdfa....".

If you want to reset that you can click the link Azure portal -> Your Website -> Dashboard -> Quick glance -> Reset your publish profile credentials.